# How can we open a link in private browsing mode

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, browser

In my web page there is a link which should be opened in private browsing mode always.
So how can I do it using HTML/javascript/jquery/php?

Comment: Looks like a requirement from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084941/how-i-can-remove-the-current-website-from-browsers-history-using-codeigniter#comment22986948_16084941. I can't see a well-intentioned reason for doing this.

Comment: You can test to set a Cookie, if a Cookie is set, that means there's no Private browsing. Than the only thing you can do is to ask the user to switch to Private.

Comment: I can see lots of well intentioned reasons for doing this. Namely, internet kiosks. You want to ensure that your user is working in a session that will be entirely destroyed when they finish. It should be as simple as closing the browser. But many internet kiosks require you to clear your own cache, history, etc. Expecting the user to open in Private Browsing? Most don't know it even exists!

Comment: I searched for a solution to at least prompt the user to open in incognito mode.And the reason is for editors to preview their article inside an iframe (as for mobile adaption check) in a not-logged in browser with a simple link created in the editorinterface. So, well-intentioned reason there =)

Can't really find a reason for how it could not be well-intended?

Comment: There is one more reason. We have an admin area with a list of registered website members. Each member has a "Login as.." link in their name which allows our support reps to "login as them". If the link would automatically open in incognito window, it would not log out our support guy (because right now the new session replaces the current one)

Comment: There are obviously plenty of reasons. And the only reason it's being discussed is the somehow-inevitable "but WHY, that's STUPID" response people can't seem to keep to themselves on most questions. It's reasonable to ask "what is your use case," or "what are the technical limitations you're operating under," or even "how have your sysadmins ridiculously limited your ability to access the outside world." "I don't see a reason for your question" is not useful input.

Comment: One more reason: I'm managing a website that is owned by the city and some of the listings are to help people against domestic violence, sexual harassment, etc. It would be great if such pages were opened in private session automatically to protect them from being stored in the browser history.

Comment: Yet another reason: I develop web page for scholars (which share their computers) and each has it's own profile with link to unique google drive folder. Folder must be shared for anyone who has the link because most scholars do not have google account. If it will be possible to open google drive in incognito window, the folder url will not be saved in browser's history and other scholars will not be able to access it easily. You can't explain all the child-users how to maintain their privacy...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's up to the user. You can't force a user to open the browser in private browsing mode.

Comment: Especially as not all browsers even have such a feature!

Comment: But is it possible for major browsers like crome, firefox, IE, safari?

Comment: No, as I said "You can't force a user to open the browser in private browsing mode"

Comment: Wondering... why not?

Comment: Why not? Because it is **fundamentally inappropriate** for a web page to be able to do such a thing.

Comment: What would be nice would be a way to attempt to open a private browsing window, and then ask the User for permission to do so.

Comment: Yes, there could be a popup like "the page wants to open this link in a private window. How do you want to open it? [Btn1: Normal window]  [Btn2: Private window]\n\n[x]Make it default behavior for this site". That could give everyone the best of both worlds.

Comment: so how do you give them the OPTION?  the problem is, as soon as you try to open a new window you've already opened it, the user *can't* make the window private.  And if it is in a mobile environment it can be a real pain for the user to try to migrate it this way.

Comment: I agree that it'd be nice to have the option to prompt the user for this, but it would be a very unexpected UI change for the vast majority of users, particularly if it were allowed without a prompt. At that point your users are likely to think you're malware, as will spam blockers.

The user likely does have the option, assuming their browser supports it; one problem here may be that many of them aren't aware of it. If you have a site for which this is important, your best bet is, unfortunately, to include text to that effect and hope your users will read it and follow your advice.

Comment: I could see ill intent on the part of advertisers - most browsers disable extensions when in private browsing mode, this includes any ad blocking software.

Comment: A feature to migrate existing windows to private mode would produce a false sense of privacy. URLs themselves often contain tracking IDs that could be used to connect a user's normal session to his incognito session. For that reason, the wall between the two sandboxes should not be easy to cross, and it must be controlled completely by the user. Windows in regular mode MUST NOT be able to affect the private browsing mode.

Comment: @Andrew Medico : I disagree. There are times when my staff are working on client machines. They need to access a private administrative website built only for their use. I do not want their login/password cached on the client computer, especially if it is malware infected. Currently I have a "at jeopardy of termination" policy that requires my field techs to use Private mode ALWAYS when repairing client computers and accessing proprietary tools, unless testing symptoms.

Comment: @AndrewMedico , could you explain why it is "fundamentally inappropriate" ?

Answer (score -1):

HTML and Javascript are used on a wide variety of programs including browsers. Even among the browsers, only a few browsers have private/incognito mode. So there cannot be a native HTML/Javascript feature to target the private browsing mode.