# HTML <a> hyperlink target inPrivate / incognito window

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way, via Javascript or other code, to open a url in a private/incognito window from an HTML page? Ideally cross-browser or at the very least IE and Firefox.

The anticipated behaviour would be along the lines of

```
<a href="http://domain.com" target="_private">Link</a>
```

The simplified reason for this is because admins want to be able to log in as users to preview various pages, but without logging themselves out. Whilst there are various other ways around this issue, this would be the simplest (assuming it is possible).

Comment: Someone already asked that [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148136/how-can-we-open-a-link-in-private-browsing-mode]

Comment: @PavelAdrian Darn - I searched and searched and couldn't find it! Even the "related" links didn't show it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Pandy Legend Did you managed to get it working? Also need a solution like this :)

Comment: checking in 2019, is this now possible? even with a pop-up notifying the user?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We can't force the visitor to view the page in an incognito/private window. Browsers provide no API that would make that possible outside of an extension.

Comment: so how do we provide this *option*?

Comment: To clarify what I mean by this, when you open a new window in Javascript, the window is already open, the user is FORCED to view it as is, they can't migrate the window to an incognito tab, especially in a mobile environment.