# Open a new InPrivate Browser Window with Button Click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

I have no idea if this is even possible, but I figured I'd ask.

I have the need to open a new InPrivate browser window from within a webpage, on a button click. I'd like to navigate to a webpage, but it has to be an InPrivate session due to issues with session state being messed up if it is not an InPrivate session. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I'm using C#, JQuery 1.11.2, and IE11.

Thank you!

Comment: Asked and answered. [HTML <a> hyperlink target inPrivate / incognito window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647899/html-a-hyperlink-target-inprivate-incognito-window)

Answer (score 0):

you can't force a user to open a window in private mode

Comment: Actually there are multiple ways to do so, it is just not all of them are very convenient / OS agnostic.