# open a link in private mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, private

The question has been asked several times a while ago but no clear answer was provided.
[How can we open a link in private browsing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148136/how-can-we-open-a-link-in-private-browsing-mode)

So can anyone share a solution to display a link on a webpage and when the user clicks on it it'll take him directly to private ( incognito ) mode?

Thank you.

Comment: "_no clear answer was provided._" Really? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16148152/1913729

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we open a link in private browsing mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148136/how-can-we-open-a-link-in-private-browsing-mode)

Comment: that is the answer? that's impossible?

Answer (score 1):

you can't force the user to open a link in private mode