# Launch Url in private mode

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

How would I launch the default browser (using `LaunchUriAsync`) in private mode?

Preferably some way without knowing the default browser.

If that's not possible, how can I add the argument that would effect that, assuming I know the browser? In that case, I'm ***not asking what that argument is***, only how to add an argument to LaunchUriAsync().

Comment: There's a [LaunchUriAsync(Uri, LauncherOptions, ValueSet)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchUriAsync_Windows_Foundation_Uri_Windows_System_LauncherOptions_Windows_Foundation_Collections_ValueSet_) override method. Have you checked it?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Yes. It doesn't look helpful.

Comment: What did you want to do by adding this parameter?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37742175/c-sharp-open-default-browser-in-private-mode/37743087#37743087

Answer (score 0):

@ispiro I checked the code on that case. If you directly use that code in your UWP app, it's unsupported. But With the Windows 10 Anniversary Update (1607), there's [launch a fulltrust process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher) API in the Desktop Extension SDK.

So, you could first make a console application/WPF application to use that code. And make a UWP app to call the `FullTrustProcessLauncher` API. At the end, create a 'Windows Application Packaging Project' and add the both as Application references to the Packaging project.

Then, you need to declare the extension in the package manifest and add a reference to Desktop Extension SDK.

More information, you could check Stefanwick's blog: [UWP with Desktop Extension](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/).