# How to open an 'incognito' window from Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, google-chrome, incognito-mode, vba

I've created links to the web in Excel but I need to find a solution how to open an 'incognito' window in my 'default' Chrome browser.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Just one of many related threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148136/how-can-we-open-a-link-in-private-browsing-mode/16148152#16148152

Comment: Yeah, I've seen some of the other questions on the topic and I kind'a had that feeling! Thanks a lot! Hope I didn't waisted anybody's time

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to accomplish this.  Create a desktop shortcut.  In that shortcut have it direct to the browser.  I did it with Chrome, so mine looked like:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Then after the link to the browser is done add the switch to open in Incognito (may differ for browser).  For Chrome it is -incognito

You then add the link you want to open, placing it inside quotes.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito "http://yourlinkhere.com"

In Excel you will link to the shortcut.  It will give you warning boxes but those are easy enough to close.  If anyone knows how to make a macro to disable them for just this click then I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works

```
Sub OpenIncognito()
Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -incognito -url https://google.com")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you make it dynamic based on the value of a cell?