# It's possible open page without cookies in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Considerer that I have so many cookies in my browser and I need open a new tab, page or poupup without my currently cookies. What I need to do?

I read in post bellow that open a private page isn't allowed:

> [How can we open a link in private browsing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148136/how-can-we-open-a-link-in-private-browsing-mode)

I tried something like

```
function openPage(){
    window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank", "height="+screen.height+", width="+screen.width);
}
```

So, is there any other possibility?

Comment: "Considerer that I have so many cookies" it's not generally possible to have more than 20 cookies / 80 kb of cookie data for any 1 site

Comment: Sorry for my expressions, but in this case I have about 5 differents cookies

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to open incognito mode, or private browsing, from JavaScript? No. This is not possible.

Comment: I tried open in incognito mode, but apparently in two cases is not possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about your site's cookies then you should not worry about it because browser will not append it to requests to any other sites

Comment: The problem in this case is that a specific cookies (this cookie is responsible for keeping me logged in to a site, for this reason I can not remove it) block my to open a new page. I never saw this before

Comment: @EricSaboia why are you doing it with `window.open` by the way? Can you use a link if it should be opened on user click? Or you can redirect it to some url on your site and configure your server to redirect this request to another (this approach should work)

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get to be able to open an private mode window is to just right click on the link and open it in one. Zero programming effort needed.

Other than that, the closest, programmatic way to do it is to have your page talk to an extension and use extension APIs which have farther reach than browser APIs. Something like [`chrome.windows.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create). You can either have the extension hook to a link on the page, or have a page script attempt to talk to the extension (if it's installed) indicating its intention to be opened in private mode.

If this is more of a workflow problem and not a programming problem, browsers like Chrome and Firefox allow you to create separate profiles. Each profile has its own dedicated storage. I often have a personal personal and a development profile, which allows me to use Chrome with storages, allowing me to blow away the cache of one while still be logged in to things with the other.