# Is it possible to open a url in private mode in any browser without using any extension

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I got one requirement that, open a URL in private mode using JAVASCRIPT.

Is it possible to open a URL in private mode with the help of JAVASCRIPT without any plugin/extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we open a link in private browsing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148136/how-can-we-open-a-link-in-private-browsing-mode)

Comment: I have been through this link, this link is quite old and no solution in it.
I thought to ask if someone has a solution to it.