# POST a form into new incognito tab

Tags: html

I have an HTML code with a form, two inputs and submit button.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
    <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
      <label for="fname">First name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
    </form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

My goal is to open a new Chrome Incognito window (or tab) and POST the form into it.

The code above is to open a new (regular) tab and post the message into it. My task is to do the same, but the new tab will be an incognito tab.

It's fine to me if it will work only on Google Chrome.

How I can do it?

Comment: It seems you can't. [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148136/how-can-we-open-a-link-in-private-browsing-mode)

Comment: what would you want to happen if they use a different browser?
It's not possible. All you can do is maybe detect if incognito mode is being used, if not, tell the user to switch to incognito

Answer (score 1):

No, **you can't**.

You may find this [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create#parameters).

But it **won't work from the web pages. But it will work from browser extensions**.